# ingress endpoint on k8s v1.26.3

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Getting below error while trying to create an ingress endpoint on k8s v1.26.3. i have created a k8s cluster using kops.

Error from server

> (BadRequest): error when creating "ingress.yaml": Ingress in version
> "v1" cannot be handled as a Ingress: strict decoding error: unknown
> field "spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.serviceName", unknown field
> "spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.servicePort"

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    env: prod
    app: demo-ms
    layer: frontend
  name: prod-demo-ingress
  namespace: prod
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.abc.in
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: prod-demo-service
              servicePort: 8080
            path: /
~~~
```

Comment: feel free to update the status of question, you can mark the naswr as accepted if found any helpful do update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prod-demo-ingress
  namespace: prod
  labels:
    env: prod
    app: demo-ms
    layer: frontend
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.abc.in
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: prod-demo-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the older ingress YAML config with latest API, this is the latest **stable**

**serviceName** & **servicePort** were part of `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`

You may have updated the **apiVersion** but forget to update other fields

Latest config

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - host: demo.abc.in
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Ref doc : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: how i will add a host, i don't see option

Comment: sorry it will be same like you are using only service part is getting change, updated answer just check the indentation if any mistake there.